# Cannot write to file using OpenCSV

Tags: java, android, opencsv

I am trying to write a file into directory. I use a RxJava in due to RxBleClient which returns result of searching bluetooth low energy clients into a ArrayList. Then I need to create and open a file with custom name to save the results into it.
I was searching on Android Doc to check if I have all permission granted, wrote some code to be sure about this - all granted. I have no clue how to resolve this problem. Below is code, stack trace and manifest file.

```java
    private void scanBleDevicesDelay(int howManyRows, String filename) {
        scanDisposable = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
                new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) // change if needed
                        .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES) // change if needed
                        .build(),
                new ScanFilter.Builder()
                        .build())
                .doFinally(() -> {
                    dispose();
                    toggleScanBleButton.setEnabled(true);
                    dumpToFileButton.setEnabled(true);

                })
                .subscribe(
                        scanResult -> {
//                            I am not proud of this :-(
                            // Process scan result here.
                            recycleViewBLEAdapter.addScanResult(scanResult);
                            scanResultsCSV.add(scanResult);
                            if (scanResultsCSV.size() == howManyRows) {
//                                CSV file writer
                                try {

                                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                            getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        // You can use the API that requires the permission.
//                                        performAction(...);

                                        File pathfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                .getAbsolutePath()
                                                + File.separator
                                                + "csvData");
                                        if (!pathfile.isDirectory()) {
//                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~IS NOT CREATING A DIRECTORY~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                            pathfile.mkdir();
                                        }

                                        File file = new File(pathfile,
                                                File.separator + filename + ".csv");
                                        if (!file.exists()) {
//                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~IS NOT CREATING A FILE~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~HERE THROWS IOException ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                            file.createNewFile();
//                                            Files.createFile(file.toPath());
                                            Log.i("File created: ", file.getName());
                                        }
                                        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
//                                        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(pathfile + File.separator + filename + ".csv"));

                                        scanResultsCSV.forEach(scan -> {
                                            String[] entries = String.format("%s,%s,%s", scan.getTimestampNanos(), scan.getBleDevice(), scan.getRssi()).split(",");
                                            Log.i("Entries", Arrays.toString(entries));
                                            writer.writeNext(entries);
                                        });
                                        writer.close();
                                        Toast.makeText(this, "Zapisano do pliku", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale("Failed")) {
                                        // In an educational UI, explain to the user why your app requires this
                                        // permission for a specific feature to behave as expected. In this UI,
                                        // include a "cancel" or "no thanks" button that allows the user to
                                        // continue using your app without granting the permission.
//                                        showInContextUI(...);
                                        Toast.makeText(this, "Nie przyznano dostępu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        // request a permission
                                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
                                    }

                                } catch (IOException ioException) {
                                    ioException.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Plik istnieje!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Nieoczekiwany blad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } finally {
//                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Zakonczono procedure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    scanDisposable.dispose();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            // Handle an error here.
                            Log.e("BLE search error", Arrays.toString(throwable.getStackTrace()));
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Nieoczekiwany blad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                );
    }
```

and in `Manifest file`:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

StackTrace:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.example.ble_rssi_plotter.MainActivity.lambda$scanBleDevicesDelay$4$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:291)
W/System.err:     at com.example.ble_rssi_plotter.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$k9iEru6y1TGq9ZgTipfCtV0GZ18.accept(Unknown Source:8)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:63)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoFinally$DoFinallyObserver.onNext(ObservableDoFinally.java:80)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.tryEmit(ObservableFlatMap.java:265)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$InnerObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:562)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onNext(ObservableDoOnEach.java:101)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:62)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onNext(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:60)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66)
W/System.err:     at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.serialization.FIFORunnableEntry$1$1.onNext(FIFORunnableEntry.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onNext(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:60)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onNext(ObservableCreate.java:66)
W/System.err:     at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.operations.ScanOperationApi21$1.onScanResult(ScanOperationApi21.java:77)
        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper$1.run(BluetoothLeScanner.java:492)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: `if(!pathfile.mkdir()) return;` Why are you continuing? It makes no sense trying to create a file in a directory that not exists! So stop and display a Toast to inform the user.

Comment: Even if I do it manually I never get to point where I create a csv file. There is always no directory so in your case just return; And if there is no directory, there is no file.
That is the main problem.